# Pointer in C (should be simple)

Tags: c, pointers

I tried code like this:

```
int *a;
*a = 10;
printf("%d",*a);
```

in eclipse and it is not printing out anything.
is it because I haven't give initial value to a?

---

Thank you that was helpful. I know it is problematic I just wasn't sure the exact problem
like, if I do `printf("%d",a);` I can see it does contain something, is it C's rule
that I do have to give it a place to point to then I can start to change the value in that address?

Comment: Herp (Undefined behavior) Derp

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- `int *a;`  This defines a variable which is a pointer to an integer type. The pointer type variable `a` at the creation contains garbage value.
- When you do `*a = 10;` it ties to use the value stored in `a` , which is garbage, as an address and store the value `10` there. Because we do not know what `a` contains and it is not allocated so `a` points to some memory location which is unknown and accessing it will be illegal, and will get you a segmentation fault (or something similar).
- Same in the case of `printf ("%d", *a);` . This also tries to access the value stored at some undefined memory location which you have not allocated.

.

```
this variable is       this is the location
stored in some         with the address 
address on the         'garbage'. You do not
stack                  have permissions to
                       access this
+-------+---------+
| name  | value   |
+-------+---------+     +---------+
|  a    | garbage |---->| ?????   |
+-------+---------+     +---------+
```

After you have defined the pointer type variable, you need to request for some memory location from the operating system and use that memory location value to store into `a`, and then use that memory location through `a`.

To do that you need to do the following:

```
int *a;

a = malloc (sizeof (int)); /* allocates a block of memory
                                    * of size of one integer
                                    */

*a = 10;
printf ("%d", *a);


free (a); /* You need to free it after you have used the memory 
           * location back to the OS yourself.
           */
```

In this case it is like below:

After `*a = 10;` . The pointer variable is allocated in the stack. At this moment the `a` contains a garbage value. Then `a` points to an address with that garbage value.

```
this variable is       this is the location
stored in some         with the address 
address on the         'garbage'. You do not
stack                  have permissions to
                       access this
+-------+---------+
| name  | value   |
+-------+---------+     +---------+
|  a    | garbage |---->| ?????   |
+-------+---------+     +---------+
```

After `a = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int));` . Let us assume that `malloc` returns you some address `0x1234abcd`, to be used. At this moment `a` will contain `0x1234abcd` then `a` points to a valid memory location which was allocated and reserved for you to be used. But note that the value inside `0x1234abcd` can be anything, ie. garbage. You can use `calloc` to set the contents of the memory locations you allocate to `0`.

```
this variable is       this is the location
stored in some         0x1234abcd , allocated
address on the         by malloc, and reserved
stack                  for your program. You have
                       access to this location.
+-------+------------+
| name  | value      |
+-------+------------+     +---------+
|  a    | 0x1234abcd |---->|  garbage|
+-------+------------+     +---------+
```

After `*a = 10;` , by `*a` you access the memory location `0x1234abcd` and store `10` into it.

```
this variable is       this is the location
stored in some         0x1234abcd , allocated
address on the         by malloc, and reserved
stack                  for your program. You have
                       access to this location.
+-------+------------+
| name  | value      |
+-------+------------+     +---------+
|  a    | 0x1234abcd |---->|    10   |
+-------+------------+     +---------+
```

After `free (a)` , the contents of `a` ie. the memory address `0x1234abcd` will be freed, ie returned back to the operating system. Note that after freeing the `0x1234abcd` the contents of `a` is *still* `0x1234abcd` , but you can no more access it legally, because you just freed it. Accessing the contents pointed by the address stored in `a` will result in undefined behavior, most probably a segmentation fault or heap corruption, as it is freed and you do not have access rights.

```
this variable is       this is the location
stored in some         0x1234abcd , allocated
address on the         by malloc. You have freed it.
stack                  Now you CANNOT access it legally

+-------+------------+
| name  | value      |
+-------+------------+     +---------+
|  a    | 0x1234abcd |     |    10   |
+-------+------------+     +---------+

the contents of a remains
the same.
```

**EDIT1**

Also note the difference between `printf ("%d", a);` and `printf ("%d", *a);` . When you refer to `a` , it simply prints the contents of `a` that is `0x1234abcd`. And when you refer `*a` then it uses `0x1234abcd` as an address , and then prints the contents of the address, which is `10` in this case.

```
this variable is       this is the location
stored in some         0x1234abcd , allocated
address on the         by malloc, and reserved
stack                  for your program. You have
                       access to this location.
+-------+------------+
| name  | value      |
+-------+------------+     +---------+
|  a    | 0x1234abcd |---->|    10   |
+-------+------------+     +---------+
              ^                 ^
              |                 |
              |                 |
      (contents of 'a')   (contents of the   )
              |           (location, pointed )
printf ("%d", a);         (    by 'a'        )
                                |
               +----------------+
               |
printf ("%d", *a);
```

**EDIT2**

Also note that `malloc` can fail to get you some valid memory location. You should always check if `malloc` returned you a valid memory location. If `malloc` cannot get you some memory location to be used then it will return you `NULL` so you should check if the returned value is `NULL` or not before use. So finally the code becomes:

```
int *a;

a = malloc (sizeof (int)); /* allocates a block of memory
                                    * of size of one integer
                                    */

if (a == NULL)
{
  printf ("\nCannot allocate memory. Terminating");
  exit (1);
}

*a = 10;
printf ("%d", *a);


free (a); /* You need to free it after you have used the memory 
           * location back to the OS yourself.
           */
```

Comment: +1 for some cracking ASCII art... Couple of things though, you're still casting the return value from malloc (see comments on other answers), you may wish to mention that when you call `printf("%d",a)` (as in the op's update), you're printing out the value of the pointer, not the pointed to value.

Comment: the `printf ("%d", a);` is a good point i will describe it with an edit. casting removed.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `printf("%p", a);` if you want the pointer address?

Comment: thank you a lot for your detailed solution!!! that really helped me understand the entire thing. one thing i wasn't sure was.. when you do free(a), a still have the value of whatever it is, but you cannot access it, meaning you cannot do *a, is it? so is a still a pointer after you do free(a)?

Comment: @Yew Long: To see the address value we can use `%p` , but printing it with `%d` will get the same value the difference is that we would get a signed decimal interpretation of the address.

Comment: @lynnyilu:yes definitely `a` still is a pointer and still points to the memory `0x1234abcd`,but accessing the memory *after* freeing the contents of `a` means freeing the reserved memory location which was reserved for you.It is like,you have hired a flat and have a duplicate key (allocation). After you give the flat away,the owner changes the locks of the flat (free). Now you do have a key to the flat , but it will not work, it is not anymore allocated for you. But now because `a` is a variable which is specially used to hold address, so you can reuse this variable to hold some other address.

Answer (score 10):

You haven't allocated memory for a.

Try

```
int *a;
a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); //Allocating memory for one int.

*a = 10;
printf("%d", *a);
free(a); //Don't forget to free it.
```

Comment: Don't forget to 1. check for `malloc` failure, and 2. `free`.

Comment: You got me there. I added the free in an edit. But you are correct. We need to check to see if we successfully allocated memory.

Comment: 3. don't cast return of `malloc`

Comment: casting the return value of `malloc` is redundant at best and may hide an error the compiler would have caught without the cast. Don't cast.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering my question!! you code really helped a lot. I put the answer to the longest coz that really must took him a while but really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the pointer, the compiler is only going to reserve memory to store a pointer variable. If you want that pointer to point to something after the fact, it has to be something that had its own memory allocated. Either point it at something that was declared as an int, or allocate memory from the heap for an int.